# Using Codeigniter on localhost

Tags: codeigniter, localhost, live, base-url

I am new with codeigniter. I have recently started work on a project which is developed in codeigniter.

I have downloaded the project and worked on it locally and then upload the updates to live.

The issue is that when i run it locally to check e.g. http://localhost/example/index.php/home or http://localhost/example/ it directly move to the live website www.example.com/index.php/home instaed of http://localhost/example, I also change the base_url in application/config/config.php.

Please assist me.

Comment: can you post your view code, so we can see where the problem is? i.e. it sounds like you have hard coded your links to the live url?

Comment: Check in the root folder for a .htaccess file, could be redirecting you to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

save this in **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```